# With Microsoft Excel VBA, can you access one sheet from another?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing some Excel VBA code and one section displays a message by selecting an entire sheet which then pops up with the desired text, Sheet2 if you like. However, the following code then refuses to run with complaint:

```
Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.
```

In the code being called I still refer to the sheet I try to modify with Sheet1, for example  `Sheet1.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(101, 101)).Value = ""`, but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because the `Cells` Object is not fully qualified.

Change your code to

```
Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), Sheet1.Cells(101, 101)).Value = ""
```

Comment: Thanks. My apologies... though it was purely `intentional` :D

Comment: @mehow: Browser issues I guess

Comment: ah yeah thats OK the point is the answer is there for anyone with same problems in the future

Comment: Sorry, I never replied - worked a treat. Many thanks.